# New Application - Page Tab - Not showing content?

Tags: facebook, iframe-app

I've been creating a new application to show a new page tab on our business page.
I followed all the steps, I set up the proper URL (iframe) for the page tab. I pushed it to my business page. Everyting seems fine but, no content is shown on the page when I click on the tab. I double-checked the url I set up, and it works fine.

What did I do wrong? I followed that guide 
http://www.facebook.com/FBML.Codes1?sk=app_217481834936914

But the steps are pretty simple in the end.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Without knowing details of what you've done it's hard to help. The guide seems to be correct, but we can't actually determine what is wrong without seeing your version. Try including code, details of your hosting, and your app's settings information.

Comment: Is your server configured to respond to POST requests at that URL? The page load from Facebook is sent as a POST request including some parameters you can use to determine which page the tab is loaded from, etc

Answer (score 1):

I made it work.

I realised that I set up http instead of https on my app settings and since my facebook was